# Python: How to catch this Error (can't source error name) - binascii.Error

Tags: python, exception, base64, binascii

I'm using the base64 module for the b64decode() function, however certain strings of text throw this error:

```
'binascii.Error: Incorrect Padding'.
```

I understand that this is because the strings are not of length multiple of 4, a requirement of base64 encoded text.

Rather than just adding '='s to the end of the string to make it a multiple of 4, I want to catch the error and simply state that the string is not base64 encoded. It works using a general 'except:', however I want to catch the specific error, but I can't find out the same of the error, as it is not very specific as with other errors, and 'except binascii.Error:' is apparently undefined. Help?

Comment: Its in the `binascii` module.

Comment: Yes, but that is not a .py file, it is a compiled C module so I cannot go tinkering inside it

Comment: You can do `import binascii` and then catch it with `except binascii.Error as e:`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The exception type is stored in `binascii.Error`, there's multiple ways of catching the exception:

```
# 1. you can import the binascii module
import binascii
try:
    pass
except binascii.Error as err:
    pass


# 2. or you can use the binascii from base64's namespace

try:
    pass
except base64.binascii.Error as err:
    pass


# 3. or you can use __import__ to do a temp import

try:
    pass
except __import__('binascii').Error as err:
    pass
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason

```
except binascii.Error
```

didn't work is because binascii was imported from within the base64 namespace, so it was undefined in my working namespace. The correct way to catch the error was

```
except base64.binascii.Error
```

Amature mistake

Comment: A-mature above all